# get ng-init value from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I want to get ng-init value from angular scope

controller

```
$scope.data={}
$scope.initvalue="myvalue";
```

Html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.value" ng-init="data.value= initvalue">
```

I want to set initvalue in input box and sent it to controller by ng-model(I want to able to modify this values so I need to make that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this make sense?

http://jsfiddle.net/c7bsrenu/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data={}
  $scope.initvalue="myvalue";
  $scope.$watch('data.value', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal);
      console.log(oldVal);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using using $watch. Please try this demo
eg :

```
<div ng-controller="yourController" >
    <input type="text" id="demoInput" ng-model="demoInput" ng-init="demoInput='value'" />
</div>
```

code in controller

```
var yourController = function ($scope) {
 console.log('demo');
 $scope.$watch("demoInput", function(){
    console.log($scope.demoInput);
 },1000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.value" ng-init="setvalue()">
```

In controller

```
 $scope.data ={}
    $scope.initvalue="myvalue";
    $scope.setvalue= function(){
        $scope.data.value = $scope.initvalue;
    }
```

This may help for you !

Comment: In your example, shouldn't this be:

<input type="text" ng-model="data.value" ng-init="init()">